# How many activations are allowed with Microsoft Office 2019 (Unlimited / FFP/ Box / Retail)?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2019

This link shows how many installations were possible for Office 2010:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/02/19/office-2013-and-office-365-installations-and-transferability/

Where can I find a similar information for Office 2019?

I'm telling about the permanent and transferable version of Microsoft Office 2019 (not 365), i.e. the unlimited version, box-packaged version, also known as FFP or Retail.

I believe Office 2020 Home & Business was installable one two computers at the same time (typically one desktop and one notebook). As far as I know, this possibility was removed with later versions of Office.

My question is also if in Microsoft's jargon "installation" an "activation" are synonyms, or on the contrary if "installation" mean the number of devices installed at the same time, so that the number of activations in a lifetime could possibly be higher.
(e.g. The software is installed only on one machine, but the user changes several times his computer over his life.)

Answer (score 0):

> Retail Office 2019 can be activated in only 1 computer per product key. If
> you want you use in more than 1 computer, you have to: Buy multiple
> product key, or. Go for Office 365.

See also:

https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/understanding-license-options-for-office

Retail licensing changed when Office 2016 / 365 subscription came out from 2 (sometimes 3) computers per license to just one.

> e.g. The software is installed only on one machine, but the user
> changes several times his computer over his life.)

So long as Office 2019 is first uninstalled on computer A, it can be moved to computer B.  This can happen as often as needed so long as only one installation exists at one time.

This method of moving licenses to new computers as needed also applies to older versions of Retail Office.

Comment: Thank you John. I was aware of the "one computer at a time" rule. Good to know that it is possible to transfer the full version as often as needed. For the 2010, version, do you know if one can also transfer as often as needed (if first uninstalling of course) ?

Comment: You can transfer as often as needed for any recent Office license so long as the first installation is uninstalled before the second is installed. This is outside of 2 computers for older versions of Office Retail.  I amended my answer accordingly.